# What is the right generic way to find any element on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, visible

I wanted to write a code which should find whether an element exists on screen or not. 
As per my requirement it should also support for an element which is inside a div that has inner scrolling.

**Assumptions are**

*1.that only one level of inner scrolling should be supported.*

*2.only visibility in context of vertical scrolling is checked.*

The main problem is the following usecase as depicted on this [link](http://agaase.github.io/webpages/demo/isonscreen.html).
An element A ($("#innerele"))  is present inside the DIV ($("#outerdiv")) which is scrollable. First you have to find out whether the DIV itself is present on screen and second then test that whether A is visible. For e.g A may be at a the top position inside DIV and thus visible, but if DIV itself is not visible then it should return false.

I could write the following code which is jquery plugin which takes care of the above requirements.  The context is the DIV which has inner scrolling inside it.

```
$.fn.isonscreen = function(context){
    //Subtract the offset of the parent container.
    //Will be 0 in case cont is undefined
    var tominus=0,
    //Add the scrollTop position incase no cont is undefined.
    toadd=0;
    if(context){
        //Find if the div is itself visible
        if(!context.isonscreen()){
            return false;
        };
        tominus = context.offset().top;
    }else{
        context = $(window);
        toadd = context.scrollTop();
    }

    if($(this).offset().top - tominus <= (toadd + context.height())){
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```

For the above link the code to find if A is on screen or not -

```
$("#innerele").isonscreen($("#outerdiv"))
```

Will this work everytime or there is some usecase where it will fail?.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433).

Comment: The solution on the above link doesnt work when I have inner scrolling enabled. E.g it doesnt work here -http://agaase.github.io/webpages/demo/isonscreen2.html. Iam trying to do - isElementInViewport(document.getElementById("innerele")) returns true even innerele is like 200px down the bottom of outerdiv.